How to make "Underbrace" text not create a gap in the equation?
Is there a way to make underbrace text not create a gap in the equation? In the line:
a_1=\sigma_1(1)\underbrace{=}_\text{example text}\pi(1)=\rho_1(1)=b_1

the presence of example text creates a gap between = and the math-y material that precedes and follows it. Is there a way to have the text display normally but remove the gap in the equation?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

I suggest you load the mathtools package -- a superset of the amsmath package -- and encase \text{example text} in a \mathclap directive.

Note also that \underbrace{=}_\text{example text} isn't exactly robust. Better to write \underbrace{=}_{\text{example text}}. For sure, \underbrace{=}_\mathclap{\text{example text}} does not work; that is precisely why I suggest \underbrace{=}_{\mathclap{\text{example text}}}.
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\mathclap' macro; load 'amsmath' automatically
\begin{document}
\[
a_1=\sigma_1(1)
\underbrace{=}_{\mathclap{\text{example text}}}
\pi(1)=\rho_1(1)=b_1
\]
\end{document}


You might use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728947/4427 with a small change that allows to specify the type of the object we want to typeset.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% use these two, rather than \underbrace and \overbrace
\NewDocumentCommand{\ubrace}{O{\mathord}mm}{#1{\underbrace{#2}_{#3}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\obrace}{O{\mathord}mm}{#1{\overbrace{#2}^{#3}}}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\ubracetext}{sO{\mathord}mm}{% *-version uses zero width
  \ubrace[#2]{#3}{% now the subscript using tabular
    \uo@brace{#1}{t}{#4}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\obracetext}{sO{\mathord}mm}{% *-version uses zero width
  \obrace[#2]{#3}{% now the subscript using tabular
    \uo@brace{#1}{b}{#4}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\uo@brace}[3]{%
  \makebox[\IfBooleanTF{#1}{0pt}{\width}]{% zero width if *-version
    \linespread{1}% just in case
    \fontsize{\sf@size}{\fpeval{1.1*\sf@size}}\selectfont
    \begin{tabular}[#2]{@{}c@{}}#3\end{tabular}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

On the same line
\[
a_1=\sigma_1(1)\ubracetext*[\mathrel]{=}{example text}\pi(1)=\rho_1(1)=b_1
\]

On two lines
\[
a_1=\sigma_1(1)\ubracetext*[\mathrel]{=}{example \\ text}\pi(1)=\rho_1(1)=b_1
\]

\end{document}

I recommend using \obrace and \ubrace, in order to avoid the quirks of \overbrace and \underbrace.

